# When transforming t in the joint probability density f (x, t), i.e. t=1/(mt+1), how does the marginal probability density f (x) transform?

Tags: probability, joint-distribution, marginal-distribution

for example, if:
$$\begin{aligned}
f_{X_{pi},T_{pi}}(x,t|*)=& \begin{aligned}\frac{\pi s^2}{\alpha_{pi}^2}\exp\left(\frac{\alpha_{pi}(x-\frac12)\nu_{pi}}{s^2}-\frac{\nu_{pi}^2}{2s^2}(t-\tau_p)\right)\end{aligned}  \\
&\times\sum_{k=1}^\infty k\sin\left(\frac{\pi k}2\right)\exp\left(-\frac{\pi^2k^2s^2}{2\alpha_{pi}^2}(t-\tau_p)\right)
\end{aligned}$$

where X=0 or 1, s=1  then $$Pr(X_{pi}=1)=\frac{\exp(\alpha_{pi}\nu_{pi})}{1+\exp(\alpha_{pi}\nu_{pi})}$$

if I transforming t into t=1/(mt+1), then the form of $Pr(X_{pi}=1)$ will be change to what?
Is it still the logistic function?

Comment: Why would any kind of operation on $t$ affect the distribution of $x$ at all?

Comment: I want to know whether the m would be in the Pr(Xpi=1). Thanks.

Comment: "Marginal" means the distribution ignores all other variables entirely.  If you're interested in the distribution of weights of giraffes ($x$) and somebody changes how they express the price of coffee ($t$), how would that affect the giraffe weight distribution??